# Geometric conditional Probability

Tags: probability, self-study

In order to start a game, each player takes turns throwing a fair six-sided dice until a $6$ is obtained. Let $X$ be the number of turns a player takes to start the game. Given that $X=3$, find the probability that the total score on all three of the dice is less than $10$.

So initially I thought this was straight forward. Total number of outcomes that three dice can sum up to less than $10$ is equal to $60$. Total amount of outcomes is $6^3=216$.
Therefore probability of the total summing to less than $10$ is $$P(\text{sum} < 10)=\frac{60}{6^3}=\frac{5}{18}$$.

However, this did not match the provided solution of $1/12$ and so I thought it had something to do with conditional probability. i.e. $P(\text{sum} < 10 | X = 3)$.

So naturally, $$P(\text{sum} < 10 | X = 3)=\frac{P(X = 3 | \text{sum} < 10) P(\text{sum} < 10)}{P(X=3)}$$

Out of the $60$ outcomes that sum less than $10$, only $6$ of those outcomes contain sixes. So that when we have to calculate the probability of taking three turns to get one $6$ we have to fail twice and succeed once and hence$$P(X = 3 | \text{sum} < 10) = \left(\frac{9}{10}\right)^2\left(\frac{1}{10}\right)=\frac{81}{1000}$$

$P(X=3)$ is simply $\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^2\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)=\frac{25}{216}$ and so finally
$$P(\text{sum} < 10 | X = 3)=\frac{P(X = 3 | \text{sum} < 10) P(\text{sum} < 10)}{P(X=3)}=\frac{\frac{81}{1000} \frac{5}{18}}{\frac{25}{216}}=\frac{243}{1250}$$

Where did I go wrong? Alternatively, maybe the textbook is incorrect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a bit difficult to point out where the mistake is because your solution is "too informal". Is the random variable $sum$ the sum of the first three dice or the sum of all dices? Depending on the definition, your probabilities change. Moreover, if $X=1$, then $sum$ might not even be defined if you consider the first definition (the sum of the three dices).

To solve the problem, lets be a bit more formal, but not too much so we do not get lost. Let $(D_i)_{i=1}^\infty$ be an infinite sequence of dice rolls, where $D_i$ is the dice result in the $i$-th roll. We have to define these variables for all possible natural numbers because your game can begin at any natural number. Let $X$ be the index $i$ of the first dice such that $D_i = 6$. That is, $X = i$ if, and only if, $D_i = 6$ but $D_j \neq 6$ for all $j < i$. Therefore, $X = 3$ if, and only if, $D_1 \neq 6, D_2 \neq 6, D_3 = 6$.

Now we define the sum as $S = \sum_{j=1}^X D_j$. That is, we sum all values up to $D_X$. The exercise asks us to compute

$$P(S < 10 | X = 3) \quad.$$

But when $X=3$, we have $S = D_1 + D_2 + 6$. Hence

\begin{align}
P(S < 10 | X = 3) 
&= P(D_1 + D_2 < 4 | D_1 \neq 6, D_2 \neq 6, D_3 = 6)\\ 
&= P(D_1 + D_2 < 4 | D_1 \neq 6, D_2 \neq 6) = 0.12\quad.
\end{align}

I leave to you as an exercise to show that the last probability is $3/25 = 0.12$. Intuitively, think of the probability of the sum of two five-sided dices being smaller or equal to $3$.

Comment: Thank you to all those who answered this question. Especially @user2974951 for coming up with a solution that would match the textbook solution. I am in agreement with the comments under that solution and have therefore voted this solution of $3/25$ as correct.

Answer (score 2):

For a more brute force approach, consider the following. You have three numbers, you know the last one is 6. There are $6 \cdot 6=36$ possible combinations for the first two numbers (assuming they can be any number from 1 to 6, which your problem seems to state that they cannot). Asking that the sum of these three numbers is $<10$ is equivalent to asking that the sum of the first two numbers is $<4$. Counting it all out you find there are 3 such combinations. Therefore $3/36=1/12$.

Comment: Albeit tempting, this reasoning does not include the fact that you have to condition on the fact that the first and the second dice are different than 6. When you do, the probability increases to $3/25$. So $1/12$ is incorrect.

Comment: This answer is very intuitive and strangely very easy now that I have seen it. I also wrote a python file to do a simulation and got the same result as your initial comment which means I am still missing something fundamentally when trying to approach this from a different point of view. But yes, a simple answer. Many thanks.

Comment: @LucasPrates You are right, considering that the first two numbers cannot be 6's then there are 25 possible combinations, which is indeed equal to $3/25$. I cannot see another way for this answer to equal $1/12$.

Comment: @LucasPrates I see the approach that was used, and I think I agree with it. Let's say I have a three digit pin and I can only use the numbers from $1$ to $6$. The last digit must be a $6$ and the sum of the first two digits must be less than $4$. My possible pin combinations are 1 1 6, 1 2 6 and 2 1 6. There are a total of $36$ possible three digit pins ending in $6$. So the proportion of pins meeting the criteria are $3/36=1/12$

Comment: @Kendall you can see it that way, however there are a total of $25$ possibilities, not $36$. It is $25$ because the first and second digit *cannot* be $6$. Indeed, there are $36$ combinations if you make no restriction, but only $25$ when you make the restriction. This is why it is $3/25$.

Comment: @LucasPrates Oh yes of course, because if you didn't make the restriction that means the game could have started on the first throw $X=1$ which is obviously not allowed. Got it.

Answer (score 1):

When we look at the sum of dice thrown, there's no importance if we got $(1,2,3),(1,4,1),(3,1,2)$ or any other permutation that gives us 6. This is called [unordered sampling with replacement](https://dlsun.github.io/probability/replacement.html). "Unordered" because the order of results doesn't matter; "with replacement" because a result can occur more than once.

The number of possible outcomes for which the sum of $n$ positive variables is $k$ is given by $\binom{n+k-1}{k}$. We have some more limitations, so a more comlex formula could be found [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/46872/how-to-compute-the-distribution-of-sums-when-rolling-n-dice-with-m-faces).

In any case, there's 1 possible rolls for sum of 3, 3 possible rolls for sum of 4, 6 possible rolls for sum of 5 and so on, totalling 81 possible rolls with sum up to 9. That probability is $\frac{81}{216}=\frac{3}{8}=0.375$, which differs from your result.